# webdav fails by https but not http

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, webdav

I'm trying to set up a webdav folder on a linux server to be used with a windows client (for now, cyberduck)

Using http, everyting is fine.
However, when using https, cyberduck warns me that my certificate is self signed, i accept and get "forbiden"
The error_log for apache gives: "AH01617: user galchun: authentication failure for "/Galchun/": Password Mismatch". Obviously my password did not change...

Here is the new conf file owncloud_and_webdav.conf:

```
Alias /Galchun /mnt/Fedaykin/Galchun
DavLockDB "/tmp/DavLock"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html/owncloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location /Galchun>
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "caladan"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/passwd.dav
    Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ####Configuration for SSL #####
    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/caladan.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/caladan.key
    #### End of SSL Configuration ####
    <Directory /var/www/html/owncloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Location /Galchun>
    DAV On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "caladan"
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/passwd.dav
    Require valid-user
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I didn't realize that cyberduck doesn't use the windows certificate store. I've deleted my answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the following line from your configuration file :

```
SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
```

Those options are not required for basic authentication.
And one of those options may break your basic authentication. If so, you found the root cause.